# incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT rails 3 and firebird

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, ruby-1.9, firebird2.5

I'm developing an application using an existing database created in firebird. When I try to fetch some data from the database and show it in a view, rails shows me that error. I realized that the database doesn't have a charset, charset = none! So, i'm trying to figure out what the problem is and how to solve it. I have to mention that the database can't be modified because it is a production database of another application. Rails only shows the error when the query gets data with tildes (´), else it doesn't have problems. This is the error I got:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError in People#index

Showing /home/guillermo/Proyecto/dcerp/app/views/people/index.html.erb where line #57 raised:

incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
Extracted source (around line #57):

54:     <% @abanits.each do |abanit| %>
55:       <tr>
56:         <td><%= abanit.init %></td>
57:         <td><%= abanit.ntercero %></td>
58:       </tr>
59:     <% end %>
60:   </tbody>
Rails.root: /home/guillermo/Proyecto/dcerp
```

ntercero is the field with the issue

I hope you can help me to solve this problem. If there is information missing just let me know. I'm going crazy! Thanks from now.

Answer (score 2):

I already fixed the issue. I just added the encode function to the line: `<td><%= abanit.ntercero %></td>` and now it looks like this: `<td><%= abanit.ntercero.encode('UTF-8', 'iso-8859-1') %></td>`. The problem came up because the encode didn't recognize the latin alphabet that includes: ñ, ó, í, á, etc. I hope this can help other people. Thanks!